# Change option menu position in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, optionmenu

I have an activity with an Option menu (Logout Icon) Inside the activity I have a fragment which is having an option menu too. But the option menu of the fragment is always coming at last. I want it before the parent activity's option menu.

Menu looks like this -

[image]

Comment: just change the position in the main menu

Comment: My main activity has many more fragment I can't add edit option menu in the main menu.

Comment: can you show us the code how you create this two icons?

Comment: Both are diffrent option menu logout is from activity and edit os from fragment.

Comment: I have just enabled hasoption menu in the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the menus is controlled by the `orderInCategory` xml attribute, where a smaller order number will appear first (left-most).

If you are inflating the menu items from XML, set the `android:orderInCategory` attribute in your Activity menu item to be higher than the one in the fragment.

If you are setting the menu items at runtime, set a higher `order` for the activity's menu item than the fragment's when calling `menu.add()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i want to do the other way. I have 1 extra option in fragment when 1 add it the activity's option is on left most I want it to be right most. How to make this possible?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO do the exact opposite of my original answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the reply